# array does not check the other array

Tags: php, arrays

My code does not work, it does not check, what can I do?

```
$ex_requests = explode(',',"1,2");
if(in_array($ex_requests, array('1', '2'))) {
    echo "OK";
} else {
exit;
}
```

returns blank page

Comment: no. more words please. "it doesn't work" is not a problem, it's just someone's opinion: *why* do you think it doesn't work? Explain what it's supposed to do, what it actually does, why you think it's doing that and what you tried to fix it, because we're here to help you, but only after you ran out of ideas and tried all other ones.

Comment: This is not a free coding service, contrary to popular belief.

Comment: Are you simply trying to test if the two values in `$ex_requests` are both in `array(1,2)`? If so, use `array_intersect()` and match the resulting count... `if (count(array_intersect($ex_requests, array('1', '2')) == count($ex_requests)) { echo 'OK'; }`

Comment: first parameter of in_array(string,array) is string and search into array

Comment: @MuhammadAli - the first parameter can be array also.

Comment: @raidenace - oh i was using in array_intersect in this condition

Answer (score 1):

When you are passing an `array` as the `needle` *(first parameter, item to search)* to `in_array()`, the `haystack` *(second parameter, item to search in)* has to be an `array of arrays`. So in your case, the following will work:

```
$ex_requests = explode(',',"1,2");

// in the next line, the first argument is an array 
// and the second argument is an array of arrays...
if(in_array($ex_requests, array(array('1','2')))) 
{
    echo "OK";
} 
else 
{
    echo "NOT OK";
}
```

This will print OK as expected.

Comment: Haha just about to post the same answer :) Well done!

Comment: @SpencerX - I remembered this because some time before I worked on this really crappy project where **every single data in memory** was arrays, array of arrays, and even more arrays lol..was a nightmare